# Include HTML webform in ASP/C# on page load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I made a webform in html and I have a website in C#.
I would like this form to show up every time the page is loaded.

What is the best way to integrate/include/call the form?
Which pages I have to modify? Default.Aspx or Default.Aspx.cs?

The purpose of this project is to show this form everytime the cookies is not set in the aspx code. 
Which I guess I have to modify the aspx part that checks if the value of the cookie is set or not and show/not show the webform based on this value.

Comment: Why don't you copy the html of your "webform" into the .aspx file that you want ? The aspx.cs is the code behind, you don't need to modify that !. As for which page to modify, it is up to you ? Try creating a new aspx page and try tinkering with it for testing.

Comment: Hi, iI wanted to modify the codebehind because there is a page_load method/function. I want this html code show up everytime the page is loaded but only if there is a cookie value set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a combination of JavaScript (to check if cookies are enabled) and JQuery. If cookies aren't enabled, have a placeholder DIV that can hold the HTML content you wanted to show. Then use $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load the html content from browser and set the DIV's innerHTML property with the returned HTML.

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: In the head of "default.master I addedd:

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" />

then in default.aspx I addedd:

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
with the entire html code inside including the html tags

Answer (score 0):

Some little progress.

That's how I modified my pages for my needs. In this way the html webform is diplaying correctly.

In the **head** of **default.master** I added:

in the **default.aspx** I added:

with the entire html of my html page (tag html included).

Now I need to modify this page that in the way this pop up is showed only if a cookie value is not set.